# How do I copy and paste text from alert popups in javascript?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, text, alert

I have some very repetitive code for a website I'm working on. To speed up this process, I wrote a quick html file that generates the code based on some inputs. When I run the code, it works. I end up with `fulloutput`, a variable with the code I need to copy and paste. I can run `alert(fulloutput)`, and it pops up in the alert box. How do I copy this text to paste it in my file? I can't just write it to the page because there's lots of raw html, and that doesn't display nicely. I'm hoping there's a way to do this without having to download node.js or anything, just to keep my life simple and so that the process is doable for even the least tech-minded people, in case I eventually pass this task on to someone else.

Comment: I'm sorry. I just read this twice and I do not clearly understand what exactly you're asking for... It seems like multiple questions in one question. I cannot determine if more code is required to even answer this question.

Comment: @Matthew It's kind of two questions, I'll split it up.

Comment: Don't use alert. `console.log()` the value and copy-paste it from the console. Or add a textarea at the start of the page and put the value there.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post

Comment: @GuyIncognito Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for.